# Як утворити іменник від слова "посмертний"

Tags: переклад, іменники, словотворення

Як саме утворити йменник від слова "посмертний"? Проглянувши словники й корпус мови, я не знайшов такого. Мені здається, що буде "посмерття", та я в цій царині не сильний, тому, можливо, використовую якийсь не той спосіб словотворення. Є якісь гарно розписані правила словотворення? А також цікаво, чи можна такий новотвір використовувати як заміну "after life".

Comment: Слово *посмертя* вже активно використовується. І здається саме в значені *afterlife*.